# dynamics ax deploy WCF service

Tags: wcf, deployment, service, axapta

When I try to register a custom service, I get this error.

> Runtime Error Code: AifSchemaStore (table), no valid executable code in method 'getCachedSchema.

Stack trace:

> (S)\Data Dictionary\Tables\AifSchemaStore\Methods\getCachedSchema
>   (S)\Data Dictionary\Tables\AifSchemaStore\Methods\getDocumentSchema - line 16
>   (S)\Classes\AifSchemaInfo\parmSchemaXml - line 19
>   (S)\Classes\AifSchemaRepository\getSharedTypesXmlSchema - line 9
>   (S)\Classes\AifServiceGenerationManager\registerService - line 43
>   (S)\Classes\AifServiceGenerationManager\main - line 20

So I can't deploy it.

Comment: Have you looked at the `getCachedSchema` method of this `AifSchemaStore` table ? This error usually means that you have compilation error(s).

Comment: Yes,when i compile AifSchemaStore i get this error: macro #AifSchemaStore_SchemaCacheScope doesn't exist at line cacheData = globalObjectCache.find(#AifSchemaStore_SchemaCacheScope, [schemaId]); .Any suggestion please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have customizations to the AIF macro that are not merged correctly after installing a CU.

- Go to the **AOT** - **Macros** - **AIF**
- Right click the **AIF** marcro an click **Compare...**
- Scroll all the way down and you should see a difference there on this line
  `#define.AifSchemaStore_SchemaCacheScope             ('AifSchemaStore_SchemaCache')`
- Merge it to the highest layer by clicking on the arrow on the lefd

Compile the `AifSchemaStore` table and the error should be gone.

You should probably check all of your customizations if they need upgrading. 
Also do a full compile of your code and generate Full CIL, otherwise you'll have a ton of problems (at least do a compile of the `AifSchemaStore` table and an incremental CIL).

Comment: thanks again but i have another problem now.i'm following this sample to deploy a service.when i'm trying to "Deploy the Data Contract Service By Using a Basic Inbound Integration Port" i get the following error : Le port « EmployeeTestServiceGroup » n'a pas pu être déployé.\nErreur :  
c:\Users\MSAX\AppData\Local\Temp\ServiceGeneration\EmployeeServiceTestGetEmployeeResponse.cs(16,16) : error CS0246: Le type ou le nom d'espace de noms 'EmployeeTest' est introuvable (une directive using ou une référence d'assembly est-elle manquante ?)

Comment: .Namespace not found refers to datacontract EmployeeTest.i'm sure i dont skip any step and compiling classes at every step without problem.the example was in http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/gg844225.aspx

Comment: Glad that fixed it, please mark my answer as a valid solution. 
For that second issue, please start by doing a full compile of your application, fix all errors and then do a full CIL until it is successfully generated. Services require a full compiled application to work. Then try to deploy again, do you still get that error? Maybe it's also better to create a new question for this.